# Spring boot(data) heisenbug with detecting database driver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

During developing Spring boot REST endpoints encounter strange(heisenbug) behavior of my application. Also might be relevant that I made separate modules for each endpoint project. In details it can run one time but fail after rerun, might run one endpoint but not another and vice versa.

> Description:
>
> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE
>
> Action:
>
> If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the
>   classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a
>   particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are
>   currently active).

My gradle config:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
//  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

and application.propperties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customers?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

server.port=8090
```

My repo:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "customers", path = "customers ")
public interface CustomerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(Long id);

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    void delete(Customer entity);


}
```

And my main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CustomerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Error stack trace:

```
2017-08-25 11:51:03.316  INFO 14116 --- [           main] c.b.e.s.p.product.ProductApplication     : Starting ProductApplication on PF0MQ6SH with PID 14116 (C:\Users\yevhen.shymko\IdeaProjects\shop\product\out\production\classes started by yevhen.shymko in C:\Users\yevhen.shymko\IdeaProjects\shop)
2017-08-25 11:51:03.321  INFO 14116 --- [           main] c.b.e.s.p.product.ProductApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-08-25 11:51:03.420  INFO 14116 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@15bb6bea: startup date [Fri Aug 25 11:51:03 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-25 11:51:05.007  INFO 14116 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2017-08-25 11:51:05.068  INFO 14116 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'managementServletContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]
2017-08-25 11:51:05.696  INFO 14116 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e6633d19] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-08-25 11:51:06.165  INFO 14116 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-08-25 11:51:06.179  INFO 14116 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-08-25 11:51:06.180  INFO 14116 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2017-08-25 11:51:06.600  INFO 14116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-08-25 11:51:06.600  INFO 14116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3184 ms
2017-08-25 11:51:07.259  INFO 14116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-08-25 11:51:07.272  INFO 14116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-25 11:51:07.273  INFO 14116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-25 11:51:07.273  INFO 14116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-25 11:51:07.273  INFO 14116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-25 11:51:07.274  INFO 14116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-25 11:51:07.274  INFO 14116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-25 11:51:07.274  INFO 14116 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-25 11:51:07.445  WARN 14116 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2017-08-25 11:51:07.449  INFO 14116 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-08-25 11:51:07.501  INFO 14116 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-08-25 11:51:07.519 ERROR 14116 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: please provide the error stacktrace.

Comment: @NarendranSolaiSridharan Done

Comment: Try to add `compile('com.h2database:h2')` to your dependencies

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is quite strange - to refresh gradle project manually after some changes.